# Can I use binary operators OR, AND inside an IFS function in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, syntax

I'm tracking progress on a the writing of a school book for little kids. In this book, there are 20 chapters, and each chapter includes 2 activities.
The person in charge came up with 5 types of activities, and since there are 20 chapters, we've got to make sure that each pair of types comes up exactly twice. We also cannot write a chapter in which the 2 activities are of the same kind. Since there are multiple authors, the way I intended to solve this was keep record of activity 1 and activity 2 for each chapter on adjacent rows and on another row, have a formula that classifies them as "combination 1 - 10". I came up with this but I get the #ERROR! message, with "formula parse error" when I hover the mouse over it. I tried to see if I could find the error, but didn't. Here's my formula, indented for ease of reading(in my spreadsheet I've removed all tabs and all spaces that are not inside quotation marks):

```
ifs(
    or(
        and(
            G2="Avalie as afirmativas"; 
            h2="Ligue os grupos"
        ); 
        and(
            h2="Avalie as afirmativas"; 
            g2="Ligue os grupos"
        )
    ),"Combinação 1",
    or(
        and(
            G2="Avalie as afirmativas"; 
            h2="Desenhe alguma coisa"
        ); 
        and(
            h2="Avalie as afirmativas"; 
            g2="Desenhe alguma coisa"
        )
    ),"Combinação 2",
    or(
        and(
            G2="Avalie as afirmativas"; 
            h2="Circule os desenhos"
        ); 
        and(
            h2="Avalie as afirmativas"; 
            g2="Circule os desenhos"
        )
    ),"Combinação 3",
    or(
        and(
            G2="Avalie as afirmativas"; 
            h2="Colagem"
            ); 
        and(
            h2="Avalie as afirmativas"; 
            g2="Colagem"
        )
    ),"Combinação 4",
    or(
        and(
            G2="Desenhe alguma coisa"; 
            h2="Ligue os grupos"
        ); 
        and(
            h2="Desenhe alguma coisa";
            g2="Ligue os grupos"
        )
    ),"Combinação 5",
    or(
        and(
            G2="Circule os desenhos";
            h2="Ligue os grupos"
        ); 
        and(
            h2="Circule os desenhos";
            g2="Ligue os grupos"
        )
    ),"Combinação 6",
    or(
        and(
            G2="Colagem"; 
            h2="Ligue os grupos"
        ); 
        and(
            h2="Colagem";
            g2="Ligue os grupos"
        )
    ),"Combinação 7",
    or(
        and(
            G2="Desenhe alguma coisa"; 
            h2="Circule os desenhos"
        ); 
        and(
            h2="Desenhe alguma coisa"; 
            g2="Circule os desenhos"
        )
    ),"Combinação 8",
    or(
        and(
            G2="Desenhe alguma coisa"; 
            h2="Colagem"
        ); 
        and(
            h2="Desenhe alguma coisa"; 
            g2="Colagem"
        )
    ),"Combinação 9",
    or(
        and(
            G2="Circule os desenhos"; 
            h2="Colagem"
        ); 
        and(
            h2="Circule os desenhos"; 
            g2="Colagem"
        )
    ),"Combinação 10")
```

I did some digging and thought that maybe it was something to with commas and semicolons, but those seem to be all correct, so my next guess would be that IFS() does not take OR() as an argument, or maybe OR() does not take AND() as an argument. None of the IFS tutorials I found go over this, so I thought to ask.

EDIT: I ended up using player0's solution because of time constraints, but digging a little deeper I found out what was wrong: In my country, we use commas as decimal separators. Therefore, every argument in any formula in sheets must be separated by a semicolon. So in the end it actually was the commas and semicolons. Funnily enough, since I've configured google in english, on the official google sheets support page formulas appear separating arguments with commas, the semicolon thing was something I found on a third-party tutorial to begin with, and it only clicked when I tried to use COUNTIF and got the exact same error, and found a question on the sheets support forum in which some guy referenced this. Thank you both for your input!

Comment: this would be a lot easier if it were set up as a VLOOKUP—easier to do, but difficult to explain here. If you'd like to share a link to your sheet (or a copy of it), being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor," I'll be happy to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF((REGEXMATCH(G2:G; "Avalie as afirmativas|Ligue os grupos"))*
    (REGEXMATCH(H2:H; "Avalie as afirmativas|Ligue os grupos"));      "Combinação 1";
 IF((REGEXMATCH(G2:G; "Avalie as afirmativas|Desenhe alguma coisa"))*
    (REGEXMATCH(H2:H; "Avalie as afirmativas|Desenhe alguma coisa")); "Combinação 2";
 IF((REGEXMATCH(G2:G; "Avalie as afirmativas|Circule os desenhos"))*
    (REGEXMATCH(H2:H; "Avalie as afirmativas|Circule os desenhos"));  "Combinação 3";
 IF((REGEXMATCH(G2:G; "Avalie as afirmativas|Colagem"))*
    (REGEXMATCH(H2:H; "Avalie as afirmativas|Colagem"));              "Combinação 4";
 IF((REGEXMATCH(G2:G; "Desenhe alguma coisa|Ligue os grupos"))*
    (REGEXMATCH(H2:H; "Desenhe alguma coisa|Ligue os grupos"));       "Combinação 5";
 IF((REGEXMATCH(G2:G; "Circule os desenhos|Ligue os grupos"))*
    (REGEXMATCH(H2:H; "Circule os desenhos|Ligue os grupos"));        "Combinação 6";
 IF((REGEXMATCH(G2:G; "Colagem|Ligue os grupos"))*
    (REGEXMATCH(H2:H; "Colagem|Ligue os grupos"));                    "Combinação 7";
 IF((REGEXMATCH(G2:G; "Desenhe alguma coisa|Circule os desenhos"))*
    (REGEXMATCH(H2:H; "Desenhe alguma coisa|Circule os desenhos"));   "Combinação 8";
 IF((REGEXMATCH(G2:G; "Desenhe alguma coisa|Colagem"))*
    (REGEXMATCH(H2:H; "Desenhe alguma coisa|Colagem"));               "Combinação 9";
 IF((REGEXMATCH(G2:G; "Circule os desenhos|Colagem"))*
    (REGEXMATCH(H2:H; "Circule os desenhos|Colagem"));                "Combinação 10";
 )))))))))))
```

Comment: I am accepting your answer since it does solve my problem, however I am curious, and would be grateful if you could explain: Why doesn't my solution work? Did I get something wrong conceptually?

Comment: @JayroBoyNeto if you are dealing with arrays the IFS is not ideal solution for the job due to array compatibility. (not mentioning that AND and OR are not supported under arrayformula either) see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124685